# Laravel 5.2 custom Middleware Levels on RESTful controllers

Tags: laravel-routing, laravel-5, restful-architecture, laravel-middleware

So from not using any framework at all, I finally forced myself to use LARAVEL 5.2 because i got tired of re-writing my own "framework" over and over again.

Anyway!

I think I'm pretty familiar with the Laravel framework and its dependencies now.

But now I need guidance on how to do this the smartest way.

I want to create a Middleware based on the companys DC.

Now every user is AUTHED by php's `envget("username");` with a re-written "auth" middleware. So far, so good. (The server is not in the DMZ btw).

The thing is, our team thought that we should populate a database-table with all the users and give them a "Privilege-level", lets say 1 through 3 where 1 is "read only", 2 is "read+modify" and 3 is "read+create+modify" with our restful controllers. But.

since we use restful controllers i cannot really give them individual Middlewares? do I manually have to change every RESTful resource in my routes.php to make this happend? or can i do this another way? I would like to keep it as simple as possible.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance
(reserved for typsos )

Comment: your information are not enough to understand your question, can you elaborate it little more? give some code or visual example to understand your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Tarre Tan
You can achieve this by adding your middleware in a parent controller's constructor. 
All your controllers that require permissions will inherit from that controller.
You have one place to adjust your permissions if you want.
Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for answering. But let me explain in more detail